# Converting a wireless mouse into a wired mouse

Tags: usb, wireless, diy

I saw this question in one of the electronics sites, and many answered him that converting wireless mouse will damage the PC's USB ports .

The question on those websites was:
I am trying to convert a wireless mouse to a wired one without using its receiver. Was wondering if signals after being received by receiver on wireless mouse are the same as those delivered by USB on wired!

My question is:
Is that possible? and why the ports may be damaged?

Comment: Just buy a wired mouse like everybody else.

Comment: I think if you read the question well you would not answer like that...

Comment: Less a danger to your PC, and more a danger of simply making a complete mess of the mouse and the adapter.  You have no idea what you are getting into.  If you just randomly connect wires together, then nothing will work right.  If you know what you are doing (and have a mouse and dongle where it could possibly be done) then it could be done safely.  But, it is pretty much guaranteed that there's no place in the dongle that you could access where you could usefully connect wires to the mouse.

Comment: If you **could** convert it, there's no reason it would "zap" the PC.  You can't convert it, though, and just randomly connecting wires and **calling** it a "conversion" could damage your PC.

Comment: The answer: 1) If you know what you're doing, almost anything is possible. 2) Ports can be damaged for any number of reasons, mechanical, electrical, chemical, you name it. This may not be the answer you want, but if you want a better answer you need to ask a better question.

Comment: No, the signals aren't the same, it would not make sense for a wireless mouse to have a USB interface because it has no USB connection. To convert a wireless mouse to USB you'd basically need to rip out all the electronics and replace it with the electronics from a USB mouse. That means just buying a USB mouse is a "more sane" option, just like Andy suggests.

Comment: Just glue a wire on and pretend.

Answer (score 4):

I will be frank, you are proposing something that is just beyond the boundaries of sanity.

It is unlikely that signals between the mouse and the dongle are USB compatible, and although technically it is possible to connect the antenna output from the mouse to the Antenna input of the dongle, it is simply not worth it, as you would have to limit the power going into the receiver, in order to avoid "zapping" it.

If you are looking at the conversion because you are tired of replacing batteries on the mouse, but don't want to buy a new one, then a slightly saner thing to do is to take a USB cable, cut off the slave end, and connect the power lines to the empty battery compartment making sure to match the voltage levels delivered by the batteries, and also ensuring that the data lines of the cable are isolated from each other and other parts.

This way you will still use the wireless data transmission, with the "unlimited" power delivered by the USB.

The fact that is is technically possible, doesn't mean that you should do it, and you should only do it if you know what you are doing. Having to fix the computer because you f*k3d up the wiring is much more expensive that a buying a new mouse.

Mice are cheap to buy, and in many cases you can get them for free, from someone that has had computers for a few years.